# Show the "Send Application" button after WPForm submitted

Tags: jquery

I combining the WPform and WP Job Manager on the application form. I want to hide this "Send Application" button and show-up after the user click the submit.

Any help please!!!

Screenshot:
[image]

This is the html sample code:

```
//This is form from WPform
<form id="wpforms-form-10963">
 <button type="submit" id="wpforms-submit-10963">Submit</button>
</form>

//This is form from WP Job Manager
<form>
 <input type="submit" class="wp_job_manager_send_application_button hide" id="apply" value="Send application">
</form>


// This is my code but it doesn't work:

$(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('#wpforms-submit-10963').on('click', function(e) {

        jQuery(this).next('#apply').removeClass('hide');

    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a working sample of what you're trying to achieve:

```js
// This is my code
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#wpforms-submit-10963').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#apply').removeClass('hide');

    });
});
```

```css
#wpforms-submit-10963{
  padding: 10px 15px; 
  background-color: #44dde2; 
  border: none; 
  text-transform: uppercase; 
  color: white; 
  border-radius: 3px; 
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px #e9e9e9;
}

#apply{
  padding: 15px 35px; 
  background-color: #44dde2; 
  border: none; 
  text-transform: uppercase; 
  font-weight: bold; 
  color: #000; 
  border-radius: 37px;
}

.hide{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

//This is form from WPform
<form id="wpforms-form-10963">
 <button type="submit" id="wpforms-submit-10963">Submit</button>
</form>

//This is form from WP Job Manager
<form>
 <input type="submit" class="wp_job_manager_send_application_button hide" id="apply" value="Send application">
</form>
```

Comment: I tried that code but not working. I think because the code doesn't readable when the WPform submitted?

The (removeClass('hide');) is not working.

Comment: @JoshuaCastilla It could be due to an outdated jQuery library. Look for your version of jQuery and then look at the documentation for that method. Or if it's not the version issue, you might want to look at the console to find out what is the culprit.

Comment: @JoshuaCastilla About the submit part... it shouldn't submit. This line `e.preventDefault();` over here should prevent it from submitting the form. If it's still submitting, I suggest you to put a `debugger;` at the start of the code (JavaScript) and then debug step by step to find the bug.